# Not all strings are translated

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, translation

I just uploaded my site to the server and for some reason some strings from plugins(for example WooCommerce which is 100% translated) and theme are not translated.

On localhost they are are translated.

What cause such a behavior?

EDIT:
I found this thread over [WPML](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/view-cart-and-checkout-page-not-translated) with same problem. but i dont have WPML installed and the company that created the theme does not want to help me to find to problematic ajax request...

Comment: How did you edit your translation? Manually? Or using a plugin such as Loco Translate or a program such as PO/MO Edit?

Comment: check your woocommerce plugin folder at `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/i18n/languages` and see if file `woocommerce-yourlang.mo` exists

Comment: Its a translation i got from the internet and i know it works because i used it before. i found this thread over [WPML](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/view-cart-and-checkout-page-not-translated) with same problem. but i dont have WPML installed and the company that created the theme does not want to help me to find to problematic ajax request...

Comment: yes they exists. and every string is translated as well.